# Dependency injection in ServerletContextListener

Tags: dependencies, code-injection, weblogic-10.x, servlets

i'm working with a Weblogib BEA 10.0 app-server.

I want to inject a StatelessSessionBean into a ServletContextListener. 
All this bean should do is start a periodic timer for clean up tasks.

My project is divided into 3 artifacts.

At first there is a war-file containing the ServletContextListener:

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

@EJB(mappedName = "ejb/cleanUpTimer")
private CleanUpTimer cleanUpTimer;

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    cleanUpTimer.activateCleanUpTimer();
}

}
```

The second artifact is a common library (jar-file) containing the interface of the EJB:

```
public interface CleanUpTimer {

  public void activateCleanUpTimer();
}
```

The third artifact is a jar containing the StatelessSessionBean:

```
    @Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/cleanUpTimer")
    public class TimedCleanUpSLSB implements CleanUpTimer {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    public void activateCleanUpTimer() {
        this.timerService.createTimer(timeout, timeout, "Clean Up Timer");  }

    @Timeout
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
    public void timedSessionCleanUp(Timer timer) {
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

When i deploy the application the Container injects "null" to the ServletContextListener.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you make sure your ejb is deployed before the servletcontextlistener fires? This might be a deployment order issue

Comment: My application is deployed as an ear and my application.xml defines the ejb-module before the web-module. So the order should be fine i guess.